# dnntabs plugin not collapsing on page load

Tags: jquery, dotnetnuke

Ok, second time posting this issue,  I posted this in wrong area the first time so aplogogies. 
I have added a multiple rows, JQuery tabs solution using custom css and the DNNTabs plugin to a module in our DNN 7.02 site.
The tabs load and work ok but are not collapsed by default on page load, they do not close the tab panes on a click event either.

I include the markup and the javascript and hope some of you dnn gurus can spot the problem

```
<div id="tabs-services-row1">
<ul class="toptabs">
    <li>
    <a href="#tabs-services-1"><span class="icon-bins">&nbsp;</span> Service 1</a></li>
    <li>
    <a href="#tabs-services-2"><span class="icon-map">&nbsp;</span> Service 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#tabs-services-3"><span class="icon-credit">&nbsp;</span> Service 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#tabs-services-4"><span class="icon-users2">&nbsp;</span> Service 4</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<!-- BINS AND RECYCliNG TAB -->
<div id="tabs-services-1" class="tab-pane">
<ul>
    <li>
    <a href="#" title="Bin collections"><span class="icon-calendar">&nbsp;</span> S1 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#"  title="blah?"><span class="icon-question">&nbsp;</span> s1 2? <!-- <span class="subitem-desc""> Here you will find this and that </span> -->
    </a>
    </li>


</ul>
</div>
<!-- End #tabs-1 -->

<div id="tabs-services-2" class="tab-pane">
<ul>
    <li>
    <a href="#"  title="blah"><span class="icon-search">&nbsp;</span> S2 1 <!-- <span class="subitem-desc"> Here you will find this and that </span> -->
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#" title="S2 1"><span class="icon-office">&nbsp;</span> S2 2<!-- <span class="subitem-desc"> Here you will find this and that </span> -->
    </a>
    </li>

</ul>
</div>
<!-- End #tabs-2 -->

<div id="tabs-services-3" class="tab-pane">
<ul>
    <li>
    <a href="#"  title="Pay your council tax"><span class="icon-credit">&nbsp;</span> S3 1 <!-- <span class="subitem-desc"> Here you will find this and that </span> -->
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#"  title="blah"><span class="icon-stats">&nbsp;</span> S3 2<!-- <span class="subitem-desc"> Here you will find this and that </span> -->
    </a>
    </li>


    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- End #tabs-3 -->
<!-- JOBS TAB -->
<div id="tabs-services-4" class="tab-pane">
<ul>
    <li>
    <a href="#"  title="BLAH"><span class="icon-pen">&nbsp;</span> S4 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#"  title="blah"><span class="icon-arrow-right">&nbsp;</span> S4 2 <!-- <span class="subitem-desc"> Here you will find this and that </span> -->
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#"  title="Supported employment"><span class="icon-support">&nbsp;</span> S4 3 <!-- <span class="subitem-desc"> Here you will find this and that </span> -->
    </a>
    </li>

</ul>
</div>
<!-- End #tabs-4 -->
</div>
<!-- End row1 *************************************************************************************************************
        ************************************************************************************************************************** -->
<!--=================================================================================================================================================================================================-->
<!-- Start row2 -->
<div id="tabs-services-row2">
<ul class="toptabs">
    <li>
    <a href="#tabs-services-5"><span class="icon-calculate">&nbsp;</span> Service 5</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#tabs-services-6"><span class="icon-earth">&nbsp;</span> Service 6</a>
    </li>


</ul>

<div id="tabs-services-5" class="tab-pane">
<ul>
    <li>
    <a href="#"  title="BLAH"><span class="icon-home-2">&nbsp;</span>S5 1 <!-- <span class="subitem-desc"> Here you will find this and that </span> -->
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#" title="BLAH"><span class="icon-pie">&nbsp;</span> S5 2 <!-- <span class="subitem-desc""> Here you will find this and that </span> -->
    </a>
    </li>

    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- End #tabs-5 -->

<div id="tabs-services-6" class="tab-pane">
<ul>
    <li>
    <a href="#"  title="BLAH"><span class="icon-blocked">&nbsp;</span> S6 1<!-- <span class="subitem-desc"> Here you will find this and that </span> -->
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#"  title="BLAH"><span class="icon-remove">&nbsp;</span> S6 2 <!-- <span class="subitem-desc"> Here you will find this and that </span> -->
    </a>
    </li>

</ul>
</div>
<!-- End #tabs-6 -->

<div id="tabs-services-7" class="tab-pane">
<ul>
    <li>
    <a href="#" # title="BLAH"><span class="icon-search">&nbsp;</span> S7 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#" title="BLAH"><span class="icon-info">&nbsp;</span> S7 2</a>
    </li>

</ul>
</div>
<!-- End #tabs-7 -->

<div id="tabs-services-8" class="tab-pane">
<ul>
    <li>
    <a href="8" title="BLAH"><span class="icon-warning">&nbsp;</span> S8 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#" title="PBLAH"><span class="icon-credit">&nbsp;</span> S8 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#" title="Apply for it"><span class="icon-pen">&nbsp;</span> S8 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
```

And now for the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(function ($) {

        $("#tabs-services-row1, #tabs-services-row2").dnnTabs({
            collapsible: true,
            active: 'false', //none
            selected: -1,
            fx: { height: 'toggle', duration: 'normal'
            }
        });

    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $("#tabs-services-row1 ul.toptabs li a").click(function () {
            $("#tabs-services-row2").Tabs('option', 'selected', -1);
        });

        $("#tabs-services-row2 ul.toptabs li a").click(function () {
            $("#tabs-services-row1,").dnnTabs('option', 'selected', -1);
        });



        $("#tabs-services-row1.tab-pane a.btn-tabs-services-close").click(function () {
            $("#tabs-services-row1, #tabs-services-row2").dnnTabs('option', 'selected', -1);
            return false;
        });


    });
</script>
```

I have not included the css as it is rather large but can include if needed although the class="dnnAdminTabNav" can be used to test.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following site http://uxguide.dotnetnuke.com/UIPatterns/Tabs.aspx
I'm also missing the surrounding:

```
<div class="dnnForm"></div>
```

But for sure this website will help you.

Comment: Not really,  as this only deals with a single row of tabs and does not have any example of collapse rows.

Comment: Is the JavaScript loaded on the $(document).ready(function ())

Comment: Trying to mock up a version using the bulit in tabs from the ui patterns mentioned earlier. and have created a couple of rows which are working, but can you collapse all the tab panes as it loads?, I have tried selected -1, active = false collapsible = true but as up to now nothing has worked